# Calling two classes that are dependent on each other in another class? -Java GUI

Tags: java, class, user-interface, object

I'm trying to restart my game after clicking a button.

This is supposed to get two screens to show up, one after the other, and those two screens are defined in two classes that are dependant on each other.

But the problem is that the first class (WordPuzzle) uses another object from the second class (Skeleton), rather than the one that I have called, while the Skeleton class I have called works as usual.

The variable **tries** sets up how many times the WordPuzzle object should run.

And **gain** is an integer that comes from the Skeleton class.

The class WordPuzzle needs an integer (from Skeleton) and a Skeleton object in order to be initialized.

The Skeleton class needs a WordPuzzle object.

```
 //define variables
 Skeleton window;



 //Inside actionPerformed

  WordPuzzle puzzlegame = new WordPuzzle(window.gain, window); // creates puzzle window but does not make it visible yet
  puzzlegame.tries = 0; //set number of tries back to 0
  puzzlegame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

  //ERROR: THE VALUES FOR CONSONANTGAIN COME FROM ANOTHER SKELETON OBJECT

  Skeleton window = new Skeleton (puzzlegame);
  window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  window.setVisible (true);

  this.dispose();
```

I hope this is familiar to you guys, I'm absolutely stumped. Thank you C:

Edit:  Although I picked the best answer, this was actually resolved after tranfering the code to the main and calling that from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i see that you have an un-initialized variable but i assume somehow you called it from somewhere ele and initialised it.

```
 Skeleton window;
`
```

//Inside actionPerformed

Here  you are creating a puzzlegame with window from skeleton, that's ok.

```
  WordPuzzle puzzlegame = new WordPuzzle(window.gain, window); // creates puzzle window but does not make it visible yet
  puzzlegame.tries = 0; //set number of tries back to 0
  puzzlegame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

Now skeleton is being created with puzzlegame and puzzlegame has skeleton window because puzzlegame was created with `Skeleton window`. You should created another window here and give that window as parmater. In java you can use `new` keyword that creates a new object.

```
Skeleton window = new Skeleton (new WordPuzzle()); //Here you need a new object
  window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  window.setVisible (true);

  this.dispose();
```

Comment: How do I create the new Window? Because as it is I get the error: "no suitable constructor found for Window(no arguments) contructor"

Comment: You have not provded enough information but be sure you create two puzzles for two windows ,or two windows for two puzzles,

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what information is needed but WordPuzzle needs an integer and Skeleton object to be constructed.

Comment: Then create a new skeleton object, copy that Integer(which you need) to new variable and then create puzzleworld or you can also clone puzzleworld but that's a tricky part.

Comment: One more thing: look call-by-value and call-by-reference in java then you will understand everything and why your code is creating trouble